# Spring Cloud Dataflow Stream Application - add folder to class path

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

I am trying to add a folder containing a property file to my class path when deploying a spring cloud stream application through the dataflow UI. I believe I want to use the java-cmd line, but when I do this I get skipper errors. Is my syntax just a little off?

[image]

also tried with quotes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the folder/directory for the classpath for property files at runtime via deployment property using `java-cmd` is not a recommended approach for this.
You can check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-whitelisting) for the documentation on the recommended way of doing this.